# Batch replace green-screen?

Tags: premiere, editing, software-recommendation, software, greenscreen

I have a video which uses a green screen in it. I have 1000 images which I want to be put onto the green screen, and each exported as unique videos. So, 1 image per video. 1000 images = 1000 unique videos (all from the same base video).

Obviously, doing this by hand is impractical. Assuming the green screen is perfectly green so there is no manual work involved, what is the best software / method to achieve this?

Comment: Premiere doesn’t support automation, but you can “paste attributes” with any effect, including keyers. After effects supports scripting/ automation. So does davinci resolve/ fusion.

Comment: This answer on Stack Exchange explains how to do it with FFMPEG https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8299252/ffmpeg-chroma-key-greenscreen-filter-for-images-video

Answer (score 1):

FFMPEG has [colorkey](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#colorkey) and [chromakey](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#chromakey) options, it does something likes

```
Overlay a greenscreen-video on top of a static background image
```

Using a shell script to loop through your thousand images on the ffmpeg command would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly and you want to export each frame as a separate video, this would actually be quite easy. Simply key your footage using after effects or any compositing program and export the footage as an image sequence. If you want to change the codec or container of the files, you can use ffmpeg to convert each file (for example .png) into a video container (for example .mp4).